# PHP Write XML with correct namespace and schema location

Tags: php, xml

I am writing XML using XMLWriter. I've been able to create

```
<foo xmlns="https://www.example.com" id="1" name="test" />
```

With:

```
$w=new XMLWriter();
$w->openMemory();
$w->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$w->startElementNS(null, "foo", "https://www.example.com");
$w->writeAttribute("id", 1);
$w->writeAttribute("name", "test");
$w->endDocument();
return $w->outputMemory(true);
```

However, what I need is to add xsi and xsi:schemaLocation, such as:

```
<foo xmlns="https://www.example.com" id="1" name="test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.example.com/myschema.xsd" />
```

I tried using this code:

```
$w->writeAttributeNS("xmlns","xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

But then I end up with:

```
<foo xmlns="https://www.example.com" id="1" name="test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

Which isn't valid, nor is it what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, just use `writeAttribute` instead of `writeAttributeNS`.

```
$w->writeAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$w->writeAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "https://www.example.com/myschema.xsd");
```